# Streamline Deployment to Heroku

Tags: heroku, command-line, automation

I have been using heroku.  I'm working alone on a small project.  Every time I deploy I have to type:

`git add .
git commit -m "the same random thing"
git push heroku master`

Is there a way to automate this so I can type `deploy`?

I'm using python for the app so if the tool were in python that would be nice.

Comment: Do you use `git` as your version control system or just for deploying to Heroku?

Comment: just to deploy to heroki

Comment: So just put those commands into one script. Heroku is using git-based deployment by default. Other option is to use api, but that's more complicated.